# How to get all jars that are residing in current dir and sub-dirs?

Tags: linux, bash

I need to find all jar files using `ls cmd` in current directory and sub-directories.

For the below directory structure:

```
path
|_to
  |_curr-dir
    |_abc.jar
    |_sub-dir1
      |_xyz.jar
    |_sub-dir2
      |_pks.jar


ls path/to/curr-dir/**/*.jar lists sub-directories jars and omits current directory jar

path/to/curr-dir/sub-dir1/xyz.jar
path/to/curr-dir/sub-dir2/pks.jar
```

I tried other wildcards, certainly I'm missing something. Any help appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: `shopt -s globstar`

Comment: @Jetchisel you should add that as an answer with explanation for Pruthvidhar.

Comment: @zedfoxus, Ill leave it here thanks.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't *need* to use `ls` and care about portability, then `find` is the best tool for the job. The command `find . -name '*.jar'` will find all `.jar` files in the current directory and its (recursive) subdirectories.

If you need to use `ls` or want something easier to remember (though less portable), you can use Bash (and Ksh)'s globstar option (enabled by `shopt -s globstar`), then `ls **/*.jar` (this is the default behavior in Zsh).

Comment: thanks! Just realized it's not a portable solution. I'm new to globbing and was trying to understand if there's something wrong with my globbing solution to obtain jars.

Comment: so my requirement is to pass path [path/to/curr-dir/**/*.jar] to a software that probably uses ls cmd to get all the jars. This software is run in a container where the bash returns these results, after your answer I tried it on my zsh terminal and it works!
We are using GNU bash, version 4.4.18(1)-release (x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu) seems like bug with globbing in bash.
Please let me know if you have any suggestions, Thank you!